# Work with OpenSSL stack_st_x509 in Swift?

Tags: c, swift, openssl, cryptography, stack

I've finally managed to get code working to validate a CMS signature in Swift using OpenSSL's `CMS_Verify` method.  Now I would like to use the `STACK_OF(X509) *CMS_get0_signers(CMS_ContentInfo *cms)` method to get the certificates used to sign the message.  In Swift, the data type for that call would be `UnsafeMutablePointer<stack_st_X509>`.  I'm able to get a value back for that call, so I know it's succeeding.  What I don't know, is how to extract the contents of it?

I was reading the [STACK API docs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API) and it appears that access to the contents of an OpenSSL stack value is accomplished using a bunch of macros in the OpenSSL code.  These macros are not carried over in Swift, however.

Does anyone know how I can go about accessing the `stack_st_x509` data in Swift?  I'm not terribly familiar with the OpenSSL APIs so I'm somewhat stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If macros are the only way to access the data you cannot do so from swift. You must write C or Objective-C code that gets the data out that you are interested in.

You can then call these wrapper functions from swift to get your data.